# Messafe fail when I restore backup gitlab but project is recovered

Tags: gitlab

I install gitbal-7.1.1 follow the tutorial in https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/
I am using Centos 6.5. I create three projects and one more user for backup:

```
Project: 
    private-project
    test-Gitlab2
    test-Gitlab  
User:
    Administrator
    test
```

The backup process is sucessful.

```
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create
```

This is the output of backup process:

```
Dumping database ...
Dumping PostgreSQL database gitlabhq_production ... [DONE]
done
Dumping repositories ...
 * root/test-gitlab ... [DONE]
 * root/test-gitlab2 ... [SKIPPED]
 * root/test-gitlab2.wiki ...  [SKIPPED]
 * root/private-project ... [SKIPPED]
 * root/private-project.wiki ...  [SKIPPED]
done
Dumping uploads ...
done
Creating backup archive: 1409819679_gitlab_backup.tar ... done
Deleting tmp directories ... done
Deleting old backups ... skipping
```

I deleted test-Gitlab project. When I restore

```
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:restore BACKUP=1409819679
```

I see some fail in output. This is a part of output:

```
Unpacking backup ... done
Restoring database ... 
Restoring PostgreSQL database gitlabhq_production ... SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
CREATE EXTENSION
psql:/var/opt/gitlab/backups/db/database.sql:22: ERROR:  must be owner of extension plpgsql
SET
SET
SET
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER SEQUENCE
...
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
psql:/var/opt/gitlab/backups/db/database.sql:2233: WARNING:  no privileges could be revoked for "public"
REVOKE
psql:/var/opt/gitlab/backups/db/database.sql:2234: WARNING:  no privileges could be revoked for "public"
REVOKE
psql:/var/opt/gitlab/backups/db/database.sql:2235: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "public"
GRANT
psql:/var/opt/gitlab/backups/db/database.sql:2236: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "public"
GRANT
[DONE]
done
Restoring repositories ...
root/test-gitlab ... [DONE]
root/test-gitlab2 ... [FAILED]
root/private-project ... [FAILED]
Put GitLab hooks in repositories dirs [DONE]
done
Restoring uploads ... 
done
This will rebuild an authorized_keys file.
You will lose any data stored in authorized_keys file.
Do you want to continue (yes/no)? yes

.Deleting tmp directories ... done
```

But when I check in gitlab. I see the project test-Gitlab is recovered. I don't know what is happening. I am not sure the restore is successful.